# What are the malleability threat vectors when passing PSBTs to other actors?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, transaction-malleability, bip174-psbt

If I am passing a PSBT ([Partially Signed Bitcoin Transaction](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki)) between multiple people, and I pass on my signature for my UTXOs for given inputs, can someone take advantage of malleability and cheat me out of the outputs I'm expecting?

What are the full ramifications of this? What is the most I can be taken advantage of, and is there any defense other than using funding with segwit spends? Can you be specific on how exactly such an attack would occur, and what portions of the PSBT might a malicious actor pay most attention to